# pytesseract ocr limit length of out characters using config

Tags: opencv, config, ocr, whitelist

I am building an application in python using opencv which extracts characters from an image and runs pytesseract to convert to text.

I know that the characters are always 2 digits longs (range 10-99). How do I configure the parameters so that single digit outputs are not returned.

I have the following in my code:

```
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename),config='--psm 100 --eom 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
```

what do I put instead of `config='--psm 100 --eom 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789'` so that it only returns 2 digit numbers (i.e. 01 but not 5)